Not able to generate public URL for specific folder
When trying to generate the public url of any folder using MegaApiClient then API takes too much time to process and not responding with anything.
Is there any settings needed to be done before this? As I am able to generate the link from Mega.IO UI.
...
// Initialize MegaApiClient
var client = new MegaApiClient();

try
{
   
    client.Login(email, password);

    
    var rootNode = await client.GetNodesAsync();

    
    var seasonFolder = rootNode.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory && n.Name == eventSeason);

    
    var eventFolder = await client.GetNodesAsync(seasonFolder);

    
    var studioFolder = client.GetNodes(eventFolder.Where(x=>x.Name == eventName).FirstOrDefault());

    List<(string FileName, string Url, string ThumbnailUrl, string DownloadUrl, bool isFolder)> lstStudioFolder = new List<(string FileName, string Url, string ThumbnailUrl, string DownloadUrl, bool isFolder)>();
    foreach (var tmpStudio in studioFolder)
    {
        // Generate a public link for the folder
        var publicLink = client.GetDownloadLink(tmpStudio);
        lstStudioFolder.Add((tmpStudio.Name, publicLink.AbsoluteUri, string.Empty, string.Empty, true));
    }
    return View(lstStudioFolder);
}
finally
{
    await client.LogoutAsync();
}

...

Error message:
time out error while trying to call client.GetDownloadLink(tmpStudio)
